# How to choose columns when creating index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

This appear to be a weird question. I know different types of indexes in sql server (clustered, non-clustered, unique, filtered, index with included column(s) ...etc) and I know how to create them. Also I know that the index depend on the query but what I don't know is who choose column when creating the index. For example, suppose a simple website that allow users to post text and images. The website has a simple two tables shown in the image :

[image: How to choose columns when creating index]

The query that get user in website is :

```
Select UserID,UserName from User where Email='something' and Password='something'
```

Suppose that I want to create index for this table, what column(s) that I should included int the creation of index ? I know that different types of indexes may include different columns but who can I decide when creating clustered or non-clustered which columns should be chosen. I see some examples of indexes that almost always choose the column after the where clause. Is this true ?

The query that gets the posts of user is :

```
Select * from Posts where UserID='something'
```

This query is different from the first query. This query may return multiple rows while the first will always return one row. Now the same question, how to choose column ?

What I want to say is how to choose columns when :

1. Creating clustered index.
2. Creating non-clustered index.
3. Creating non-clustered with included column(s).

The above example is just to illustrate the idea of the question. The goal is not to find a good index for the two queries in the example, but to come up with a base that can be used to help in choosing columns when creating index.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In perfect world, you'd like to index columns, that appear in `WHERE` clause or `JOIN` condition. In your case it would be `Email` and `Password` columns.

So you could go for a nonclustered index on User table and on Email and Password.

So pretty much this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_User_Email_Password
    ON dbo.User (Email, Password);
```

So if you will run this query:

```
SELECT UserID, UserName
FROM User
WHERE Email = 'something'
    AND Password = 'something';
```

You will end up using just created index (most likely) or Clustered index and it will seek trough it. However, your query selects UserID and UserName, which are not included in your index, as a result, your query will do a Key Lookup (it will find records in a created index and will look back at your `dbo.User` table to find matching values for SELECT statement (UserID and UserName). To avoid that, you could create index with `INCLUDED` columns to remove a Key Lookup (and you would want to do that).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_User_Email_Password
    ON dbo.User (Email, Password)
    INCLUDE (UserID, UserName);
```

Using this index you will have a nice NON CLUSTERED INDEX seek in your execution plan.

Also, choosing indexed columns order matters. Let's say, your table would contain UserTypeID (there are not many of them). So you would pass some specific UserTypeIDs and a list of UserIDs, then SQL Server would probably want to pick an index, which has UserTypeID as first indexed column.

So some tests:

```
CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    UserId INT
    , UserName VARCHAR(500)
    , Email VARCHAR(500)
    , Password VARCHAR(500)
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Users_UserID
    ON #Users (UserID);

-- Some test data from my DB
INSERT INTO #Users (UserId, UserName, Email, Password)
SELECT TOP (10000) UserId, UserName, Email, 'password'
FROM Users;
```

So this is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Users;
```

This will perform index Scan, since we don't specify any details.
[image]

Now if we specify UserId it will Seek your Clustered index (we have UserId as key):

```
SELECT *
FROM #Users
WHERE UserID = 602;
```

[image]

Now let's create index without included columns and query something:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Users_Email_Password
    ON #Users (Email, Password);

SELECT *
FROM #Users
WHERE Email = 'k0641088@kingon.a.uk';
```

As I've told, it uses created index and does a Key Lookup, it finds matching Email and password and finds rest of the columns in your table to output them (P.S. If you would be ouputting, let's say, only Email, it wouldn't do a Key Lookup, it wouldn't be needed):
[image]

Now let's create index with included UserName and run query above. It will produce this nice execution plan with plain NonClustered Index seek as I told you before:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Users_Email_Password_iUserName
    ON #Users (Email, Password)
    INCLUDE (UserName);
```

[image]

This is a high-quality article and I'd recommended reading it: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/index-selection-and-the-query-optimizer/

Comment: For the query :

SELECT UserID, UserName
FROM User
WHERE Email = 'something'
    AND Password = 'something';

As you say we can index Email and Password and Include UserID and UserName as included columns in the index. If  UserID is indexed through clustered index, do I need to include UserID as included column in the non-clustered index ? What happen here for the key Lookup  ?

Comment: If `UserID` is your Clustered index, you shouldn't include it. You can try both of course.

Comment: But the query still need to do a Key Lookup to find UserName. Does what I say true ?

Comment: You're correct. I'll update answer with more details.

Comment: @SQLPolice Thank you! I've now updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'ld prefer to 
create a non-clustered index on email and password can be an included column
and create a clustered index on UserId which is probably an auto-increment column

Comment: As I say in the question, the goal is not to find good index for the query. The intend is to find some bases that can help in choosing columns to be indexed